# Showing that an Intermediate extension is Galois

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading a theorem involving a number field $K$ and some particular field $L$ with $K\subset L\subset \overline{K}$ which the author defines (none of the extensions is necessarily finite).

Right after he defines $L$, he argues that $L/K$ must be *Galois* because it satisfies:

$$\sigma(L)\subset L\text{ for all }\sigma\in Gal(\overline{K}/K)$$

(no other argument was given)

Since I'm unfamiliar with infinite Galois theory, I'm not confident about this kind of arguments.

Does Galois really follow from that property? Why?

Is it correct to say that $L/K$ is Galois $\Leftrightarrow \sigma(L)\subset L$ for all $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{K}/K)$? (again, the extensions are not finite a priori)

Comment: Since $K$ is perfect, the extension $\overline{K}/K$ is Galois.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree, but why is $L/K$ Galois?

Comment: Does this not follow from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290882/why-are-subextensions-of-galois-extensions-also-galois)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the answers in the link you sent explain why $\overline{K}/L$ is Galois. But I know how to prove that. What I'm trying to find out is: how do I prove $L/K$ is Galois based on the information that $\sigma(L)\subset L$ for all $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{K}/K)$

Comment: It is correct what you said. What is your definition of Galois?

Comment: @DocteurCottard an extension is Galois $:\Leftrightarrow$ normal and separable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody has pointed out, $L/K$ is separable since $K$ has characteristic zero and is hence perfect.

Since the definition of Galois is to be normal and separable, we see that $L/K$ is Galois if and only if it is normal. But one definition of normality is that $\sigma(L)=L$ for all $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(\overline K/K)$ for an algebraic closure $\overline K$ of $K$. Furthermore, since we are dealing with automorphisms, we actually have $\sigma(L)=L$ if and only if $\sigma(L)\subset L$.

Comment: The definition of normality I know is this: if an irreducible polynomial $p\in K[x]$ has a root $a\in L$, then every other roots of $p$ are in $L$. How does it follow from $\sigma(L)\subset L$ for all $\sigma$?

Comment: Okay, well what I wrote is equivalent and I’d recommend trying to prove it