# If $\alpha \in E$ is not fixed by any automorphism and $E$ is Galois, $E = F(\alpha)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

The following is a problem from Allan Clark's Abstract Algebra textbook:

> Let $E$  be a Galois extension of a field $F$. If $\alpha \in E$ is fixed only by the identity automorphism, show that $E = F(\alpha)$.

The author seems to expect me to prove this with only the definition of a Galois extension:

> A finite extension $E$ of $F$ is Galois if $F$ is the fixed field of a finite group of automorphisms of E. This group is called the Galois group.

As well as the following theorem:

> The order of a Galois extension is equal to the order of a Galois group.

Here is my approach:

Let $f \in F[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. If $m$ is the degree of $f$, then by this fact:

$$F/(f(x)) \cong F(\alpha) \subseteq E,$$

we know that $m \leq [E : F]$. As every automorphism of $E$ which fixes $F$ permutes the roots of $f$, my idea was to show that there are at most $m$ possible permutations of those roots which may arise by applying an automorphism. Then, if $m < [E : F]$, we'd have two distinct automorphisms $\varphi_1, \varphi_2$ which both mapped $\alpha$ to the same element. Therefore, $\varphi_1 \varphi_2^{-1}$ would fix $\alpha$ which would be a contradiction. Then $m = [E : F]$ would imply $F(\alpha) = E$.

Unfortunately, I can't think for a possible bound for a number of valid permutations other than the obvious $m!$. I'm not sure if this approach can be fixed or if it's completely useless.

Comment: Note that $F(\alpha)\subseteq E$ and that extension is, of course, Galois.

Comment: @lulu is that obvious from the definition of Galois given? That statement seems essentially equivalent to the question in hand.

Comment: @lulu Why is this obvious? I had thought of this but dismissed it immediately because of the counterexample(?) $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$/($x^3 - 2)$, where the latter extension is clearly Galois, but the former clearly isn't.

Comment: Consider $F\subseteq F(\alpha)\subseteq E$.  Both extensions are clearly separable.  To see that the second is also normal, choose $\beta\in E$ and let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F(\alpha)$ and let $q(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F$.  Of course, $p(x)$ splits completely over $F$ and $q(x)$ must divide it, so it must split completely over $F(\alpha)$.

Comment: Note that your example is not relevant as we are not claiming that $F(\alpha)$ is Galois over $F$.  As you remark (and as that example shows) that claim is not generally true.  Indeed, in that example the big field is cyclic of order $2$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] {2})$.

Comment: @lulu I understand that what you've given is an equivalent condition, but I don't think the author expects me to prove that equivalence, as that is done later on in the text. Instead, I'm looking for a direct proof from the definition I've provided.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290882/why-are-subextensions-of-galois-extensions-also-galois) is a question specifically about the Galois nature of subfields.

Comment: I don't understand.   Surely we have to use the definition of a Galois extension and the definition of a Galois group.  In any case, I don't see any way to proceed without those definitions.

Comment: Right, but I think what's expected is to apply the definition I've referenced in the post:

A finite extension $E$ of $F$ is Galois if $F$ is the fixed field of a finite group of automorphisms of $E$. This group is called the Galois group.

Comment: You should add that you assume $E$ to be a finite extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sigma_1=\text{id},\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n$ be all the automorphisms of $E$ which fix $F$.  Then we have under the hypotheses of question $[E:F] =n$.

Consider the polynomial $$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\sigma_i(\alpha))\in E[x] $$ Applying any automorphism $\sigma_j$ permutes the factors of $f$ and hence $f(x) $ is fixed by all of them and therefore $f(x) \in F[x] $.

We show that $f(x) $ is irreducible over $F$ as well. Let $g(x) \in F[x] $ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ so that $g(x) $ divides $f(x) $. Then each of the distinct $\sigma_i(\alpha) $ is a root of $g(x) $ (because $g(x) \in F[x] $) and thus $f(x) $ divides $g(x) $. It follows that $f(x) =g(x) $ and $f(x) $ is irreducible. Thus $F(\alpha) $ is of degree $n$ over $F$ and hence $E=F(\alpha) $.