# Subgroups of splitting field of n-th root of the unit

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\xi$ be an $n$-th root of the unit. Is there any number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subseteq\mathbb Q(\xi)$? Give an example or show why not.

I've tried using the fact that $|\mathbb Q(\xi):\mathbb Q|=\phi(n)$ there $\phi$ is Euler's function, so if the statement is true for some $n$ then $3\;|\;\phi(n)$. Doesn't seem to lead anywhere tho.

Comment: All the subextensions of a Galois extension are also Galois, $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbf{Q}$ is Galois but $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbf{Q}$ is not.

Comment: @Tuvasbien I think it's not true that all subextensions of a Galois extension are also Galois. Take the Galois extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}, i)$. The problem is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ is not Galois.

Comment: @DavidHuélamoLongás $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ is not Galois as $\zeta_4\sqrt[4]{2}\notin\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291034/702179 for a proof of what I claim.

Comment: @DavidHuélamoLongás: Every irreducible polynomial that has a root in a Galois extension splits in it.  It's mentioned on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension) wikipedia page.  Since $X^3-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, and $\Bbb{Q}(\xi)$ is Galois, if $\alpha$ is in it, $X^3-2$ would split in it.

Comment: @Tuvasbien I guess you are using $\zeta_4$ to denote a primitive fourth root of the unit. But then $\zeta_4=i$ and it's obvious that $i\sqrt[4]{2}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What's the splitting field of $\alpha$?  It should have a property that cyclotomic fields don't share.

Comment: What's the splitting field of $\alpha$? I've only worked with splitting fields of polynomials.

Comment: What's the smallest Galois field containing $\alpha$?  And what's its Galois group?

Comment: @Dzoooks if my numbers are right, the splitting field of $\alpha$ is $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of the unit. It's Galois Group has 6 elements and is $D_3$. It's not abelian. Is that the property you were supposing me to find?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Dzooks and once you find that fact, how would you get to the contradiction? I posted an answer that shows this contradiction, but I would like to know if there's another that maybe is more straightforward. Thank you :D

Comment: What you posted is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to make a guess with some of your answers.
Suppose $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\xi)$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$. Given that $E:=\mathbb Q(\xi)$ is a Galois extension, it follows that $\mathbb Q(\xi)$ contains the splitting field of $\alpha$, which is $L:=\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega\right)$ where $\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is a primitive third root of the unit. I found that Gal$(\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega\right))=D_3$, which is not abelian. Gal($\xi$) is abelian. From Galois fundamental theorem we have that $D_3=\mathrm{Gal}\left(L/K\right)\cong \frac{\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)}{\mathrm{Gal}(E/L)}$. But $\mathrm{Gal}(E/L)\leq \mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$ so $\mathrm{Gal}(E/L)$ has to be abelian. Quotient of abelians is abelian, and thus $D_3$ is abelian. This is a contradiction.

If you see any mistake please let me know